# Is possible custom autocomplete with ng-tags-input ? [AngularJS]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-tags-input

Is possible to create custom autocomplite with `ng-tags-input`?

I have response like this from server:

[image]

This is how I get autocomplite for country and address:

`search.data.suggest.country[0].options`

This retrun array of objects:

```
[
    {"text": "Puerto Rico", "score" : "1"}
    ...
]
```

`search.data.adress.country[0].options`

Here is my try just for contry which not working...

```
$http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/gym/autocompletion?q=' + query)
    .then(function(search) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        console.log(search.data.suggest.country[0].options);
        deferred.resolve(search.data.suggest.country[0].options);

        return deferred.promise;
    });
```

This will display error:

```
angular.js:13550 TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at ng-tags-input.min.js:1
    at processQueue (angular.js:15961)
    at angular.js:15977
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17229)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17045)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17337)
    at angular.js:19166
    at completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:5869)
    at angular.js:6145
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: It looks like you're getting this error because 'search' in '.then(function(search) {'  is undefined

Comment: Error message: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined.  This means that it can't find a property on an undefined variable.  Based on the code you provided, that variable is search because you're trying to do this:    search.data.suggest.country[0].options

Comment: Could you update your question and provide the markup you're using?